# producing a bathymetric map in qgis with limited depths measurements

Tags: qgis, bathymetry

i am new to your community and hope you to find tips on how to work with the following project.

i want to produce a bathemetric map (depths profile) of a water area. I do have aerial images and 3 cross sections with depth measurements.
at first i would like to "connect" the depth lines to receive contour lines as used in mapping elevation and form there on estimate the depth at places where no measurements are taken. i do really have an idea on how to start as i only have done some remote sensing before.
Please ask if i have not described it accurately enough.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to tackle this?

much thanks in advance!